# What is the purpose of std::scoped_allocator_adaptor?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11, containers, allocator

In the C++11 standard we have `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor` in the dynamic memory management library. What are the most important use cases of this class?

Comment: @dyp No, not yet. I will give it a read.

Comment: There's some encoding weirdness at the end of @dyp's URL - `http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2554.pdf%E2%80%8E` - try [this one instead](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2554.pdf). (`%E2%80%8E` is a URL-encoded UTF-8 [left-to-right-mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark).)

Comment: @Casey Thanks, removing my comment. Copied the URL from a google search ;)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you want a container of strings and want to use the same allocator for the container and its elements (so they are all allocated in the same arena, as TemplateRex describes) then you can do that manually:

```
template<typename T>
  using Allocator = SomeFancyAllocator<T>;
using String = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Allocator<char>>;
using Vector = std::vector<String, Allocator<String>>;

Allocator<String> as( some_memory_resource );
Allocator<char> ac(as);
Vector v(as);
v.push_back( String("hello", ac) );
v.push_back( String("world", ac) );
```

However, this is awkward and error-prone, because it's too easy to accidentally insert a string which doesn't use the same allocator:

```
v.push_back( String("oops, not using same memory resource") );
```

The purpose of `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor` is to automatically propagate an allocator to the objects it constructs *if they support construction with an allocator*.  So the code above would become:

```
template<typename T>
  using Allocator = SomeFancyAllocator<T>;
using String = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Allocator<char>>;
using Vector = std::vector<String, std::scoped_allocator_adaptor<Allocator<String>>>;
                                   /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
Allocator<String> as( some_memory_resource );
Allocator<char> ac(as);
Vector v(as);
v.push_back( String("hello") );  // no allocator argument needed!
v.push_back( String("world") );  // no allocator argument needed!
```

Now the vector's allocator is automatically used to construct its elements, even though the objects being inserted, `String("hello")` and `String("world")`, are not constructed with the same allocator.  Since `basic_string` can be implicitly constructed from `const char*` the last two lines can be simplified even further:

```
v.push_back( "hello" );
v.push_back( "world" );
```

This is much simpler, easier to read, and less error-prone, thanks to `scoped_allocator_adaptor` constructing the elements with the vector's allocator automatically..

When the vector asks its allocator to construct an element as a copy of `obj` it calls:

```
std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct( get_allocator(), void_ptr, obj );
```

Normally the allocator's `construct()` member would then call something like:

```
::new (void_ptr) value_type(obj);
```

But if the `allocator_type` is `scoped_allocator_adaptor<A>` then it uses template metaprogramming to detect whether `value_type` can be constructed with an allocator of the adapted type. If `value_type` doesn't use allocators in its constructors then the adaptor does:

```
std::allocator_traits<outer_allocator_type>::construct(outer_allocator(), void_ptr, obj);
```

And that will call the nested allocator's `construct()` member, which uses something like placement new, as above. But if the object does support taking an allocator in its constructor then the `scoped_allocator_adaptor<A>::construct()` does either:

```
std::allocator_traits<outer_allocator_type>::construct(outer_allocator(), void_ptr, obj, inner_allocator());
```

or:

```
std::allocator_traits<outer_allocator_type>::construct(outer_allocator(), void_ptr, std::allocator_arg, inner_allocator(), obj);
```

i.e. the adaptor passes additional arguments when it calls `construct()` on its nested allocator, so that the object will be constructed with the allocator. The `inner_allocator_type` is another specialization of `scoped_allocator_adaptor`, so if the element type is also a container, it uses the same protocol to construct *its* elements, and the allocator can get passed down to every element, even when you have containers of containers of containers etc.

So the purpose of the adaptor is to wrap an existing allocator and perform all the metaprogramming and manipulation of constructor arguments to propagate allocators from a container to its children.

Comment: Doesn't the vector allocator ( std::scoped_allocator_adaptor<Allocator<String>> ) need to be explicitly told that its inner allocator is Allocator<char>?  This explanation is very helpful but it doesn't seem to cover the use of the inner-allocator template argument(s) for scoped_allocator_adaptor.  I expected to see "std::scoped_allocator_adaptor<Allocator<String>, Allocator<char>>".  Am I just confused?

Comment: ...Oh I think I see...  the scoped allocator COULD be told exactly what the inner allocator type is, but since Allocator<string> and Allocator<char> are closely related and can even be constructed from one another (evidently), it's good enough to give an Allocator<string> instance to string() and rely on an implicit conversion to construct the needed Allocator<char> from that.  (Unless I'm more confused than I thought.)  And in a different case where the two levels' allocators were NOT so related, the scoped allocator WOULD need to be explicitly told about both via its template parameters.

Comment: @mjwach, correct. In the general case you'd use the variadic template argument list of `scoped_allocator_adaptor` to nest different allocators for the different levels of nested elements

Comment: And since writing those comments I have also learned ( from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator ) that being able to copy/move/cast an Allocator<string> into an Allocator<char> and the like is just part of the contract a set of allocator types must fulfill in order to be considered true allocators (if I'm reading right).  So that's the main thing I was missing here, having only had a piecemeal education on these topics.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Great answer. You didn't mention anything about performance here. So I expect that the allocator adapter doesn't affect performance of the allocator at all.

Comment: @Nikos all it does is call another function with the relevant arguments. The only overhead is the cost of a (potentially inlined) function call.

Answer (score 6):

Say you have a stateful arena allocator `Alloc` with a constructor `Alloc(Arena&)` that allows some special performance for your application, and say that you use a nested hierarchy of containers like this:

```
using InnerCont = std::vector<int, Alloc<int>>;    
using OuterCont = std::vector<InnerCont, std::scoped_allocator_adaptor<Alloc<InnerCont>>>;
```

Here, the use of `scoped_allocator_adaptor` will let you propagate the arena object used to initialize your allocator from the outer to the inner container like this:

```
auto my_cont = OuterCont{std::scoped_allocator_adaptor(Alloc<InnerCont>{my_arena})};
```

This achieve **greater data locality** and lets you pre-allocate one big memory arena `my_arena`  for your entire container hierarchy, rather than only make `my_arena` available for the outer container, and requiring a loop over all innner containers with another arena for each element at that level.

The class template is actually a variadic template that gives you fine-grained control about which type of allocator to use in each type of the container hierarchy. Presumably this gives complicated data structures better performance (I must confess I haven't seem different allocators in different levels in action anywhere, but maybe large data centers with multi-million users have a use case here).