# How to use std::scoped_allocator_adapter?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, std, allocator

As far as I understand, `std::scoped_allocator_adapter` provides a control mechanism for specifying **separately** which allocator will be used by a container, by its elements, by elements of their elements, etc. assuming the elements themselves are containers.

That said, I am having trouble understanding the semantics of `std::scoped_allocator_adapter`.

Bjarne Stroustrup provides the following 4 examples in *The C++ Programming Language*, section 34.4.4, pg. 1001(I will refer to them as *Example-1*, *Example-2*, etc. in my questions to follow.):

> We have four alternatives for allocation of vectors of strings:
>
> ```
> // vector and string use their own (the default) allocator:
> using svec0 = vector<string>;
> svec0 v0;
>
> // vector (only) uses My_alloc and string uses its own allocator (the default):
> using Svec1 = vector<string,My_alloc<string>>;
> Svec1 v1 {My_alloc<string>{my_arena1}};
>
> // vector and string use My_alloc (as above):
> using Xstring = basic_string<char,char_traits<char>, My_alloc<char>>;
> using Svec2 = vector<Xstring,scoped_allocator_adaptor<My_alloc<Xstring>>>;
> Svec2 v2 {scoped_allocator_adaptor<My_alloc<Xstring>>{my_arena1}};
>
> // vector uses its own alloctor (the default) and string uses My_alloc:
> using Xstring2 = basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, My_alloc<char>>;
> using Svec3 = vector<xstring2,scoped_allocator_adaptor<My_alloc<xstring>,My_alloc<char>>>;
> Svec3 v3 {scoped_allocator_adaptor<My_alloc<xstring2>,My_alloc<char>>{my_arena1}};
> ```

For the sake of completeness, `My_alloc` is defined in the book like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct My_alloc { // use an Arena to allocate and deallocate bytes
    Arena& a;
    My_alloc(Arena& aa) : a(aa) { }
    My_alloc() {}
    // usual allocator stuff
};
```

Now, off to my questions:

---

Question-1: In *Example-3*, does the **elements** of `Svec2` use `My_alloc<char>{my_arena1}` to allocate storage for their elements(of type `char`)?

---

Question-2: If so, does it have anything to do with the fact that `Xstring` uses the custom allocator `My_alloc<char>` in its definition? IOW, even if `Xstring` were defined with another allocator, wouldn't the **elements** of `Svec_2` **still** use `My_alloc<char>{my_arena1}` since `scoped_allocator_adaptor` of `Svec2_` dictates which allocator to use for allocations done by `Svec_2` **and** allocations done by its elements(of type `Xstring`)?

---

Question-3: Consider the code below which is supposed to be a variation on *Example-3*. Does `v2_` elements(of type `std::string` in this case) use `My_alloc<char>{my_arena1}`? If not, which allocator do they use?

```
// both v2_ and its elements to use My_alloc<some_type>{my_arena1}
using Svec2_ = 
    vector<string, scoped_allocator_adaptor<My_alloc<string>>> // value_type std::string, instead of Xstring 
Svec2_ v2_ {scoped_allocator_adaptor<My_alloc<string>>{my_arena1}};
```

---

Question 4: Based on the explanation on www.cppreference.com I quoted below, it seems to me that in *Example-4*, `Svec3` does **not** use its **default** allocator `std::allocator` to allocate storage for its elements(of `Xstring2` type), but rather the "outer allocator", which is `My_alloc<xstring>`. **Elements** of `Svec3`, on the other hand, **will** use `MyAlloc<char>` which is the "inner allocator". (And not because it is the allocator specified in the definition of `Xstring2`, but because it is the "inner allocator" in `scoped_allocator_adapter` of `Svec3`.)

This is what it says on www.cppreference.com in `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor` section:

> Given:
>
> ```
> template< class OuterAlloc, class... InnerAlloc > class
>     scoped_allocator_adaptor : public OuterAlloc;
> ```
>
> A container constructed directly with a scoped_allocator_adaptor uses
>   `OuterAlloc` to allocate its elements, but if an element is itself a
>   container, it uses the **first** inner allocator. The **elements** of that
>   container, if they are themselves containers, use the **second** inner
>   allocator, etc. If there are **more** levels to the container than there 
>   are inner allocators, the **last inner** allocator is reused for
>   **all** further nested containers.

Based on that, shouldn't the correct example be as follows?

```
// v3_ uses its default allocator(or rather std::allocator), while its elements use My_alloc
using Xstring2 = basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, My_alloc<char>>;
using Svec3_ = 
    vector<Xstring2, scoped_allocator_adaptor<std::allocator<Xstring2>, My_alloc<char>>>;
Svec3_ v3_ {
    scoped_allocator_adaptor<std::allocator<Xstring2>, My_alloc<char>>{my_arena1}
};
```

This way, doesn't this use of `scoped_allocator_adaptor` dictate that allocations by `Svec3_` use `std::allocator`, while its **elements** use `My_alloc<char>{my_arena1}` for their allocations?

---

I can tell I have fundamental misunderstandings of the scoped allocator model. Can someone point out what I am missing?

Comment: General point: I would always use a bunch of alias templates when using allocator adaptors to keep the notation clean, otherwise you just drown in noise. Start with something like `template <typename T> using ScAlloc = std::scoped_allocator_adaptor<MyAlloc<T>>;`. Then you can easily spell things like `vector<T, ScAlloc<T>>`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22148258/819272

Comment: @KerrekSB I was fortunate enough to notice the [link](https://rawgit.com/google/cxx-std-draft/allocator-paper/allocator_user_guide.html) you have provided in the brief time that it appeared in your comment. I have no idea why you decided to erase it, but it is indeed a great read. Nonetheless, the only example provided there(under *propagation* section) is very similar but not the same as the *Example-3* in my post. (In *Example-3*, the container used as the element uses a non-scoped allocator, whereas in the mentioned link, it uses a scoped one.)

Comment: @Kemal: The linked guide didn't discuss *multiple* nested allocators in the scoped allocator adaptor, so I figured it was of no use for your problem. And yes, once you go down the scoped allocator route, you always want to use scoped allocators, which is why I would always start with the alias template.

Comment: @TemplateRex I had already read that link before I posted mine. Yet again very informative post by Jonathan Wakely. Unfortunately it is not about the differences in usage that my post is rather about.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

**Question-1**:
Yes.

**Question-2**:
No.

**Question-3**:
No.
Its default allocator (= `std::allocator<char>()`) is used.

**Question-4**:
You are right.
(But both Example-4 and its modified-version cannot be compiled because they lack a constructor argument for outer allocator.)

**Can someone point out what I am missing?**:
I don't think that you misunderstand something, but rather you only forget that `My_alloc` cannot be used for `std::string` because an allocator type of `std::string` is `std::allocator`, not `My_alloc`.

Remember that an allocator is just used for an constructor argument, so an allocator which have a different type cannot be used.
As Jonathan Wakely pointed out, when `Svec2` or `Svec2_` creates an its element, it calls:

```
std::allocator_traits<std::scoped_allocator_adaptor<My_alloc<xxx>>>::construct(
    get_allocator(), void_ptr, args...
);
```

where `xxx` is `Xstring2` for `Svec2` or `std::string` for `Svec2_`.
It calls `get_allocator().construct(void_ptr, args...)`, and then it calls any one of:

```
std::allocator_traits<My_alloc<xxx>>::construct(
    outer_allocator(), void_ptr, std::allocator_tag, inner_allocator(), args...
);
```

if constructor call `xxx(std::allocator_tag, inner_allocator(), args...)` is well-formed.

or

```
std::allocator_traits<My_alloc<xxx>>::construct(
    outer_allocator(), void_ptr, args..., inner_allocator()
);
```

if constructor call `xxx(args..., inner_allocator())` is well-formed.

or

```
std::allocator_traits<My_alloc<xxx>>::construct(
    outer_allocator(), void_ptr, args...
);
```

if constructor call `xxx(args...)` is well-formed.

In these examples, both `outer_allocator()` and `inner_allocator()` have the type `My_alloc<xxx>`.
The `std::basic_string` and all allocator-aware containers have constructors whose last argument is an allocator for all constructor overloads.
So, if the `inner_allocator()` (the type `My_alloc<xxx>`) is convertible to the allocator type of the elements, the second form is called (i.e. the allocator is used); otherwise the third form is called (i.e. the allocator is never used).

For `Xstring2`, the allocator type is `My_alloc<char>`, and `My_alloc<Xstring2>` is convertible to `My_alloc<char>`. So, the elements of `Svec2` are constructed by `Xstring2(args..., inner_allocator())`, then their internal memory are allocated by `My_alloc<char>`.
By constrast, the allocator type of `std::string` is `std::allocator<char>`, and `My_alloc<Xstring2>` is not convertible to `std::allocator<char>`. So, the elements of `Svec2_` are constructed by `std::string(args...)`, then their internal memory are allocated by default allocator (= `std::allocator<char>()`).

FYI: Strictly speaking, it is determined by `std::uses_allocator` whether the third form is used or not.